# Laravel project hanging, doesn't terminate kernel request and doesn't send any response

Tags: php, laravel

I've encountered an issue with my Laravel project where it hangs indefinitely. After I `php artisan serve`, the page continuously loads with no response and no timeout.

I've tried to debug and found out that the problem is happening in:

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
)->send();
```

I pushed and pulled changes in controllers (didn't change anything else). However, after these edits, the project now hangs indefinitely upon loading.

I've tried only to re-download the project and ensured correct database configuration, Couldn't think of another solution to try. Please tell me in the comments if I need to add any extra information.

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
php version: 8.2.4
laravel's php version: 8.0.2
laravel version: 9.2
```

## EDIT

1: I've Also tried to run it on vhost and `php -S localhost:8000 -t .` and still nothing chagned
2: Turns out that even localhost/phpMyAdmin doesn't work too in the same way

**NOTE**: when I run apache on xampp server, the `80` `443` ports changes to `64129` `64130`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone faces this bug in the future: The problem were because of xampp, turns out that I've runned it mutiple times, I closed it and restarted the serve and it worked 
if it still not solving it, check if there's PORT conflicts